# React JS merge word/excel template (dot/dotm, xlt/xltm) into single docx/xlsx

Tags: reactjs, excel, vba, ms-word

we are moving front-end of our application from Java to React JS. In app user can export some data with Office template files. In case of word its .dot/.dotm file + data + description (excel is .xlt/.xltm + data + desc). These file are created on server side (linux) then copied to client  PC and launched by single .dot/.xlt file which merge them into single .doc/.xls file.

Word example:

```
├───startHere.dot
├───templateFile.dot
├───dataFile.tmp
└───descFile.dat
```

"descFile.dat" only describe other three files for macro. It tells which file is template, which is data file and output name. This four files are downloaded to client PC and then launched via cmd which **create single .doc file**:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL excel.exe /e /p "path" startHere.dot
```

Unfortunatelly as far as I know launch cmd is not possible in React JS. Is there some utility which could merge these files in React JS and output for browser would be word.docx / excel.xlsx?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for a way how to to Word mailmerge (docx template) or insert data into Excel template (xlsx) here are awesome packages:

Word: https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-templates

Excel: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate#XlsxPopulate

The problem is performance on client side (using React JS). Merge one word / excel with data is really fast with these packages. But perform dozens of data source takes a lot of time. You have to try it on your own.